# 動詞の不規則変化などを考慮しながら英単語の出現頻度を求めたい

Tags: テキストファイル, 自然言語処理

数万～数十万語規模の単語が含まれた英語のテキストファイルがあり、そのテキストに含まれる全単語の出現頻度を求めたいと考えています。

ただし動詞の時制や三単現、名詞の複数形などの理由により単語に変化があっても、それらは同一視した上での頻度を求めたいです。

例えばテキスト中に以下の単語がそれぞれ

```
go : 3
gone : 6
went : 2
goes : 1
going : 4
```

の回数だけ出現したとして、これらを全て巻き上げて基本型`go : 16`とカウントしたいということです（さすがに have gone などまでは同一視しなくてよいです）。また動詞だけでなく名詞の複数形、形容詞の比較級なども同一視してカウントしたいです。文脈を見ないと区別の付かない lie - lay / lay - laid のような単語の問題はありますが、それについては考慮せずにどちらかに寄せてしまって構いません。

何も考慮しなくてよければ shell でワンライナーで書けてしまう処理であることは理解しています。しかし単語の変化まで考慮するとなると、すぐに思いつく手では、別途単語辞書を持った上でマッピングしていくような処理が必要となりそうで、結構ごりごりと力技が要りそうに思われます。

しかしこのような要求ははるか昔からありそうに思われるので、もしすでに同様の処理を行うスクリプトなりツールなりが存在するなら助かるのですが、どなたかご存知ないでしょうか。
あるいは、このような処理を簡便に行うアプローチが他にありますでしょうか。

条件としては

- Linux / FreeBSD / Windows のいずれかの環境で動作するもの
- できれば無償で手に入るもの

であることが望ましいです。

Comment: シェルの環境で動けば、言語はなんでも構わないということですね？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi 結果が得られるならshellに限らずGUIアプリでも可です。言語も問いません。

Comment: @user10685 さんの回答を受けて related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization

Comment: stemming (語幹の切り出し)で英語に限ればPorter Stemmerがよく使われています。実装もいろいろあります。単数複数とか-ing, -lyなどの語尾を削って正規化するのにはかなりの精度があります。検索エンジンで索引をつくるときの前処理が主な用途で、辞書形にするものではないのですが参考まで。

Comment: ありがとうございます。皆さんからの情報のおかげで [lemmatizer - Google 検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=lemmatiser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=ja#hl=ja) をキーワードにすれば目的とするものにたどり着けそうです。最終的に形にできたらここで報告させていただきます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

信用度足りずコメントできないので曖昧ですが回答欄に失礼。
[TreeTagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/)という形態素解析ツールで得られたlemma([基本形…？](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%BD%99%E7%B4%A0))を使って分類すれば目標は達成できそうです。

Comment: 大雑把に「同じ単語だけど形が違うやつ」をまとめて[lexeme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme)(形態素), そのなかで代表させる形が [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_%28morphology%29)（"辞書形"でもいいのかも)，単語をその形にするのが [lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)，という流れなんですね．

Answer (score 3):

いくつかのツールやライブラリの使用を検討しましたが、最終的に @user10685 さんからご紹介いただいた [TreeTagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) で前処理を行うことにしました。

以下に実行手順を示します。実行は Linux (Fedora22) 環境です。

### 1. tree-tagger のインストール

上記リンク先の Download に記載の手順をそのまま行います。
今回は処理対象が英語であるため、パラメータファイルには [English parameter file](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/english-par-linux-3.2-utf8.bin.gz) を利用しました。

### 2. tree-tagger の実行結果をsedスクリプトに変換する

```
$ cat input.txt | ./cmd/tree-tagger-english | sort | uniq | awk '$3 != "@card@" { if ($1 != $3) printf("s/\\b%s\\b/%s/g\n", $1, $3) }' | uniq > command.txt
```

単語をカウントしたい英文ファイルを`input.txt`としています。
上記のワンライナーでいったんsedのスクリプトファイル`command.txt`を生成します。
`command.txt`の内容は次のようにひたすら置換コマンドが並んだものとなります。

```
s/\bexposed\b/expose/g
s/\bexpressed\b/express/g
s/\bexpressions\b/expression/g
s/\bextended\b/extend/g
s/\bextends\b/extend/g
s/\beyelids\b/eyelid/g
s/\beyes\b/eye/g
s/\bfacilitated\b/facilitate/g
s/\bfacilitates\b/facilitate/g
s/\bfacilitating\b/facilitate/g
s/\bfacilities\b/facility/g
```

### 3. sedスクリプトで英文ファイルをlemmatizeする

```
$ sed -f command.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

生成したsedスクリプトで不規則変化等している箇所をすべてlemma形式に一括変換します。

たとえばこんな文章が

> No, I am not aware. I know of three different instances when he has bought ropes; he bought two ropes on one occasion, and one on another.

こんな風に変換されます。

> no, I be not aware. I know of three different instance when he have buy rope; he buy two rope on one occasion, and one on another.

### 4. lemmatizeしたファイルを元にして単語出現数を数える

```
$ cat output.txt | tr -d ',.;:()"\t' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -dr > count.txt
```

これで単語ごとの出現数を求めることができました。

```
   4938 the
   3207 
   2999 be
   2211 of
   1675 to
   1465 that
   1349 I
   1152 a
   1095 and
   1084 you
     :   :
```